# Probabilistic Analysis: HIRE-ASSISTANT Problem

Tags: probability, analysis, probabilistic-method

Consider the below problem on Hiring Assistant

> In HIRE-ASSISTANT, assuming that the candidates are presented in a random order, what is the probability that you hire exactly one time?

```
HIRE-ASSISTANT(n)
    best = 0 // candidate 0 is a least-qualified dummy candidate
    for i = 1 to n
        interview candidate i
        if candidate i is better than candidate best
            best = i
            hire candidate i
```

P(Hire exactly one)

= P(hire only 1st person) + P(hire only 2nd person) + ...

$= \frac{(n-1)!}{n!} + \frac{(n-1)!}{n!} + ...$

$= \frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{n} + ...$

$= 1$

I'm getting wrong result can anybody tell me what I'm asuming wrong here.

Comment: How can you hire only the second person? Don't you always hire the first person at least?

Comment: If I'm interpretting it correctly, you are asking the following: when computing the max of a set, what's the probability you make one replacement of the current best max?

Well since you are starting with candidate 0 (dummy) then you guaranteed make one replacement at $i =1$, so that can be the only replacement. Meaning that the best candidate was first.

This occurs with $P = 1/n$.

Comment: To be precise, it is $\frac {1}{\text{number of people better than 0}}$. You must admit that some people aren't better than dummies and could be a net drag on the company.